# How to iterate if else statement over data frame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python. Please help me solve below problem.

I have a data set (sample data) given below and I want to create a new column called salary_range. Please suggest how can I iterate if else statement over a data frame to create a new column "Salary_range"

DataFrame:

```
Name Salary Salary_Range 

A     10       Low

B     8        Low

C     21       Medium

D     22       Medium

A     23       Medium

R     25       Medium

K     31       High

A     33       High      

L     34       High

M     41       Very_High

N     44       Very_High
```

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]** and your latest attempt.

Comment: No.There was not any reason.

Comment: Take a look at `dataframe.apply`

Comment: In the dataset given below you already have a column called Salary_Range

Comment: Would like to create a column Salary_Range

Answer (score 0):

**df.loc** creates a new column if it doesn't exist. I think you want something like this:

```
filter = (df['Salary'] > 35)
df.loc[filter, 'New_Salary_Range'] = 'VERY HIGH'

filter = (df['Salary'] > 30) & (df['Salary'] <= 35)
df.loc[filter, 'New_Salary_Range'] = 'HIGH'

filter = (df['Salary'] > 20) & (df['Salary'] <= 30)
df.loc[filter, 'New_Salary_Range'] = 'MEDIUM'

filter = (df['Salary'] < 20)
df.loc[filter, 'New_Salary_Range'] = 'LOW'
```

I hope that was helpful (:

Comment: Thanks. Is there any better way to do this,using if else statement?

Comment: Here you can see implicit if-elif-else statements.